# merge two tables without common columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to merge two tables without common columns in MSSQL while keep all the rows in each table as separate row in the merged table.

Scenario:

```
Table A    Col1    Col2
    1      1.Col1  1.Col2 
    2      2.Col1  2.Col2

Table B   Col3
    3     3.Col3
```

Here is what i expected:

```
Table  Col1   Col2    Col3
    1  1.Col1 1.Col2  Null
    2  2.Col1 2.Col2  Null
    3  Null   Null    3.Col3
```

Comment: A simple answer would be to add empty columns to the select from each table and then union the two result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Union` and select `NULL` for other columns to avoid:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table #Table1 ( A int,  Col1 varchar (10),   Col2 varchar(10))
Create table #Table2 ( b int,  Col3 varchar (10))

insert into #Table1 values (1,'1.Col1',' 1.Col2')
insert into #Table1 values (2,'2.Col1','2.Col2')

insert into #Table2 values (3,'3.Col3')

select A,Col1,Col2,null as Col3 from #Table1
union 
select B,null,null,Col3 from #Table2

go
drop table #Table1
go
drop table #Table2
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A,Col1,Col2,null as Col3 from tblA Union All Select B,null ,null ,Col3 from tblB
```